# How to update the highcharts.js to make the export server to my own ipaddress,instead of connect to the highcharts server?

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

When the web brower clike the export button to export the picture,sometimes I find that it will connect to the highcharts export.com server.But my picture should be private,so how to prevent to connect to highcharts server?Can I put the export in my own web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your own exporting server, for further information please visit the website 
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server/